# What is wrong with my attribute-searching XPath query

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I have an XPath query which looks right to me, but isn't returning any results.

The XML document it's being tested against:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="foo" Source="foo.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

The code:

```
Xml = new XmlDocument();
Xml.LoadXml(text);
Manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(Xml.NameTable);
//use constants for namespaces to make more readable
Manager.AddNamespace("a", NS_DEPLOYMENT_2007); //use 'a' for default namespace here so xpath is easier
Manager.AddNamespace("x", NS_XAML_2006); 

string xpath="//a:Deployment.Parts/a:AssemblyPart[@a:Source='foo.dll']";
var tmp = Xml.SelectNodes(xpath, Manager);
```

What is wrong with my XPath query here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the namespace prefix from your attribute:

```
string xpath="//a:Deployment.Parts/a:AssemblyPart[@Source='foo.dll']";
```

You only need to specify the namespace for the attribute if it explicitly has a namespace defined, so when you would want to query the `Name` attribute, you would have to add it:

```
string xpath="//a:Deployment.Parts/a:AssemblyPart[@x:Name='foo']";
```

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* this part is your problem:

```
@a:Source='foo.dll'
```

Unlike element names, attribute names don't inherit a namespace. Your document doesn't specify a namespace for the attribute, so I don't think you should do so either.

Try just:

```
@Source='foo.dll'
```

(As an aside, I would personally use LINQ to XML instead of XPath - I find it generally simpler. YMMV, but it may be worth considering - if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, of course.)

From ["Namespaces in XML 1.0 (3rd edition)" section 6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) (emphasis mine):

> The scope of a default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself.
>
> A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope. **Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.**